# Die historische Verwendung von Femininsuffixe auf Namen

Tags: gender, history, person-names

Der Text auf diesem Gemälde wundert mich.

[Die Ehefrau Barbara vom Uhrmacher Sebastian Baumann in Friedberg](https://www.museen-in-bayern.de/uploads/tx_landesstelle/images/Portraet_der_Friedberger_Uhrmachersgattin_Barbara_Baumann__1727-1798___1768__OeL_auf_Leinwand__Museum_im_Wittelsbacher_Schloss_Friedberg__Inv._Nr._61.JPG)

Warum steht hier *Barbara Baumannin* und nicht *Baumann* ? Ist das *-in* ein Femininsuffix oder ist das etwas anders? Ich kenne die Verwendung vom Suffix in der Umgangssprache (die Moserin usw.), hier steht es aber auf einem Gemälde als Überschrift. Scheint mir ungewöhnlich, obwohl das Gemälde aus dem 18. Jahrhundert ist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sieht mir so aus, als wär das ganz einfach der tatsächliche Name, genau so gebildet wie von Dir vermutet. Allerdings wie Moserin wohl regional unterschiedlich beliebt.

Ein Beispiel dafür aus dem angegebenen Zeitfenster:

> [Maria Marg. Baumanin, 1755 - 1788
>   Maria Marg. Baumanin ist geboren worden 1755, in Geburtsort.
>   Maria hat Michael Baumanin geheiratet 1772, im Alter von 17 in Hochzeitsort.
>   Sie haben einen Sohn bekommen: Nicolaus Vendl.
>   Maria starb am Tag Monat 1788, im Alter von 33 in Sterbeort.](https://www.myheritage.de/names/barbara_baumanin)

Und eines das es noch deutlicher macht:

> [Barbara Baumanin, 1699 - 1708
>   Barbara Baumanin ist geboren worden 1699, zu Jacob Bauman.
>   Barbara starb im Monat 1708, im Alter von 9 in Sterbeort.](https://www.myheritage.de/names/barbara_baumanin#)

Comment: Das sind keine echte "Beispiele". Das sind Formulare, wo man "Geburtsort", "Sterbeort" usw. eintragen soll.

Comment: Maria hat Michael “Baumannin” geheiratet?!?! Was für ein Schmäh!

Answer (score 3):

Katharina von Bora (der Mädchenname der Ehefrau von Martin Luther) war nach ihrer Heirat auch als *die Lutherin* bekannt.

Früher war das eine übliche Bildung, um die Ehefrau eines Mannes beim Nachnamen zu adressieren. In manchen Regionen und Dialekten (z.B. im Schwäbischen) ist das durchaus auch heute noch teilweise üblich.

Die Bildungsform folgt dabei denselben Regeln wie z.B. Berufsbezeichnungen (Bäurin, Ärztin,...). In den slawischen Sprachen gibt es ähnliche Formen (Putin - Putina/Putinova)